# How to a point belong a function with animation?

Tags: pstricks, animations, animate, pst-plot

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,pst-plot,pst-calculate,amssymb,amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-4.5,-6)(1,2.5)
\def\a{\pscalculate{8/3}}
\def\b{\pscalculate{16/3}}
\psaxes[labels=none,Dx=2,Dy=\a,xlabelPos=top,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-4.5,-6)(1,2.5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
\psplot[plotpoints=500,linewidth=1.2pt,yMaxValue=2.1,yMinValue=-6]{-5}{3.5}{1/3*x^3+2*x^2+4*x}

\uput[-45](0,0){$O$}
\uput[90](-2,0){$-2$}
\uput[90](-4,0){$-4$}
\uput[0](0,-\a){$-\dfrac{8}{3}$}
\uput[0](0,-\b){$-\dfrac{16}{3}$}
\uput[135](-2,-\a){$A$}
\uput[180](-4,-\b){$B$}
\psline[linestyle=dashed](0,-\a)(-2,-\a)(-2,0)
\psline[linestyle=dashed](0,-\b)(-4,-\b)(-4,0)
\psdots*(0,0)(-2,0)(-4,0)(0,-\a)(0,-\b)(-2,-\a)(-4,-\b)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Question:

How to A-point moved from B-point to O and opposite with animation.

I have no many knowledge about animate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

works only with `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pstricks,pst-plot,pst-calculate,animate,amsmath}
\begin{document}

%-------------------- write timeline file ---------------------%
\newwrite\TimeLineFile
\immediate\openout\TimeLineFile=Func.txt
\immediate\write\TimeLineFile{::0x0,1}%
\multido{\i=2+1}{40}{\immediate\write\TimeLineFile{::\i}}
\immediate\closeout\TimeLineFile
%------------------- end timeline -----------------------%

\psset{algebraic}

\def\Func{1/3*x^3+2*x^2+4*x}
\def\b{\pscalculate{16/3}}

\def\drawFunc#1{%
    \edef\Y{\pscalculate{1/3*(#1)^3+2*(#1)^2+4*(#1)}}
    \psCoordinates[arrows=->,linecolor=blue,linestyle=dashed,
        dotstyle=o,dotscale=2,showpoints](#1,\Y)
    \uput[90](#1,0){$#1$}
    \uput[0](0,\Y){\Y}
    \uput[135](*#1 {\Func}){$A$}
}   


\begin{center}
\begin{animateinline}[controls,palindrome,timeline=Func.txt,
    begin={\begin{pspicture}(-4.5,-6)(1.1,2.75)},
    end={\end{pspicture}}]{10}
    %---- static material: axes, labels, curve ----%
  \psaxes[labels=none,xlabelPos=top,
          ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-4.5,-6)(1,2.5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
  \psplot[plotpoints=500,linewidth=1.2pt,yMaxValue=2.1,yMinValue=-6]{-5}{3.5}{\Func}
  \psCoordinates[arrows=->,linestyle=dashed,dotstyle=o,dotscale=2,showpoints](*4 {\Func})
  \uput[-45](0,0){$O$}
  \uput[90](-4,0){$-4$}
  \uput[0](0,-\b){$-\dfrac{16}{3}$}
  \uput[180](-4,-\b){$B$}
  \psCoordinates[arrows=->,linecolor=blue,linestyle=dashed,dotstyle=o,dotscale=2,showpoints](*-4 {\Func})
  \newframe
    \multiframe{41}{rX=-4+0.1}{\drawFunc{\rX}}%
\end{animateinline}% 
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]

and the same as a gif animation:

[image]

Using it without a timeline:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{article}
\usepackage[paperwidth=8cm,paperheight=10cm,margin=0mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{pst-plot,pst-calculate,multido,amsmath,animate}
\newpsstyle{coor}{arrows=->,linecolor=blue,linestyle=dashed,dotstyle=o,dotscale=1.5,showpoints}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
    \psset{algebraic}

    \def\Func{1/3*x^3+2*x^2+4*x}
    \def\b{\pscalculate{16/3}}

\def\drawFunc#1{%
  \begin{pspicture}(-4.5,-6)(1.1,2.75)      
     \edef\Y{\pscalculate{1/3*(#1)^3+2*(#1)^2+4*(#1)}}
     \psCoordinates[style=coor](#1,\Y)
        \uput[90](#1,0){$#1$}
        \uput[0](0,\Y){\Y}
        \uput[135](*#1 {\Func}){$A$}
    \psaxes[labels=none,xlabelPos=top,ticks=none]{->}(0,0)(-4.5,-6)(1,2.5)[$x$,-90][$y$,0]
    \psplot[plotpoints=500,linewidth=1.2pt,yMaxValue=2.1,yMinValue=-6]{-5}{3.5}{\Func}
    \psCoordinates[style=coor](*-4 {\Func})
    \uput[-45](0,0){$O$}
    \uput[90](-4,0){$-4$}
    \uput[0](0,-\b){$-\dfrac{16}{3}$}
    \uput[180](-4,-\b){$B$}
\end{pspicture}%
}   

\begin{animateinline}[poster=last, controls, palindrome]{10}%
    \multiframe{41}{rA=-4.0+0.1}{\drawFunc{\rA}}%
\end{animateinline}

\end{document}
```

Comment: With the timeline file we can draw objects only one time which will never be repeated, e.g. coordinate system, curve, ... Without we have to plot for every step the complete function with all elements. It depends on how complicated the static stuff is if a timelime is recommended. For your example a solution without would also work.

Comment: Wow, I see.....Good code!

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\usepackage{pstricks-add,mathtools}
\def\f{1/3*x^3+2*x^2+4*x}
\psset
{
    unit=2cm,
    xfractionLabels,
    xfractionLabelBase=2,
    dx=\pscalculate{1/2},
}

\begin{document}
\foreach\x in{14,13,...,0}{%
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-4.6,-5.1)(1.3,2.8)
\psCoordinates[linestyle=dashed](*-3.5 {\f})
\psCoordinates[linestyle=dashed](*{-\x\space 4 div} {\f})
\psaxes{->}(0,0)(-4.4,-4.9)(1,2.5)[$x$,0][$y$,90]
\psplot{-3.9}{.5}{\f}
\end{pspicture}}
\end{document}
```

[image]